# Excel formula to format URL Regex

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, regex, microsoft-excel-2016

I need to create Regex for Black listing that takes all variations of URL - http:// or https:// with or without www. I came up with this:

Url:
https://www.example.com/contactus.aspx

Regex:

```
(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?example\.com\/contactus\.aspx
```

I have hundreds of those URLs so about year ago I have created excel formula to format this:

```
=CONCATENATE("(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?",(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(LEFT(MID(A2,FIND("//",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("//",A2)-1-(RIGHT(A2)="/")),4)="www.", RIGHT(MID(A2,FIND("//",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("//",A2)-1-(RIGHT(A2)="/")), LEN(MID(A2,FIND("//",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("//",A2)-1-(RIGHT(A2)="/")))-4), MID(A2,FIND("//",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("//",A2)-1-(RIGHT(A2)="/"))),"/","\/"),".","\.")))
```

Its not pretty but it works - sort of. I just noticed the issue when URL contains + or ? it does not escape character as `"\+" or "\?"`.

Url:
http://example.com/Site/Find+The+Site.php?lang=en

Regex:

```
(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?example\.com\/Site\/Find+The+Site\.php?lang=en
```

Its been a while and I can't figure out how I came up with this formula in the first place - probably there is better way to do this.

Expected regex is: `(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?example\.com\/Site\/Find\+The\+Site\.php\?lang=en`

My current workaround is to process the URL to escape + and ? using   `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"?","\?"),"+","\+")` before running my formula. I'd like to incorporate the above SUBSTITUTE so one formula will handle www/http/https and escape +, ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. It's not really clear what you're asking here. Could you edit your post and include a specific question with hoped-for outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could just include your `SUBSTITUTE` in the formula:

```
="https?://(?:www\.)?" & MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( I1,"/www.","/"),"+","\+"),".","\."),"?","\?"),FIND("//",I1)+2,999)
```

*Note that I did not escape the **solidus** in the regex. Whether that is necessary depends on whether the language is using the solidus as a pattern delimiter.  In Excel VBA Regular Expressions, that is not the case. In others, it may be. So you may need to add another nested `SUBSTITUTE`, and make some other minor changes, to take care of that*

eg:

```
="https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?" & MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( I1,"/www.","/"),"/","\/"),"+","\+"),".","\."),"?","\?"),FIND("//",I1)+4,999)
```

Given your URL, `http://example.com/Site/Find+The+Site.php?lang=en`

the first formula would return:

```
https?://(?:www\.)?example\.com/Site/Find\+The\+Site\.php\?lang=en
```

and the second:

```
https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?example\.com\/Site\/Find\+The\+Site\.php\?lang=en
```

Comment: The second formula works great however when URL is prefixed with www it returns:`https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?www\.example\.com\/Site\/Find\+The\+Site\.php\?lang=en` instead of `https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?example\.com\/Site\/Find\+The\+Site\.php\?lang=en` this is [my regex test](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=117356)

Comment: @mthq If I understand you correctly, one just can add another `SUBSTITUTE` to remove the `/www.` if it is present.  I have edited my answer to correct that.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!